# Bad value for attribute sizes on element img on w3 validator

Tags: html, validation

while validating my [page on w3](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fitpro.preprod.coreapp.didev.co.uk%2Fit-legislation%2F27814%2Fwhat-is-gdpr-everything-you-need-to-know) I get lots of errors like:

> Bad value (max-width: 768px) 321px,(min-width: 768px)
>   407px,(max-width: 768px and min-resolution: 2dppx) 642px,(min-width:
>   768px and min-resolution: 2dppx) 814px,321px for attribute sizes on
>   element img: Bad media condition: Parse Error at …resolution: 2dppx)

I understand that something is wrong with the `sizes` attribute, but still can't find out what
This is the html

```
<img 
class="polaris__image lazyload" 
alt="" 
height="188"  
role="presentation" 
sizes="(max-width: 768px) 321px,(min-width: 768px) 407px,(max-width: 768px and min-resolution: 2dppx) 642px,(min-width: 768px and min-resolution: 2dppx) 814px,321px" 
src="https://media.itpro.co.uk/image/upload/t_card-mobile@1/v1570816514/itpro/2019/04/arcserve_udp_9240dr.jpg" 
srcSet="https://media.itpro.co.uk/image/upload/t_card-mobile@1/v1570816514/itpro/2019/04/arcserve_udp_9240dr.jpg 321w,https://media.itpro.co.uk/image/upload/t_card-desktop@1/v1570816514/itpro/2019/04/arcserve_udp_9240dr.jpg 407w,https://media.itpro.co.uk/image/upload/t_card-mobile@2/v1570816514/itpro/2019/04/arcserve_udp_9240dr.jpg 642w,https://media.itpro.co.uk/image/upload/t_card-desktop@2/v1570816514/itpro/2019/04/arcserve_udp_9240dr.jpg 814w" width="321"
/>
```

Is the combined use of max/min-width and min-resolution an error?I alkso tried using PPI but it still returns an error.

Comment: Maybe do try-error approach and try to understand what is wrong.

Comment: @Justinas The error is in the max-width/min-resolution part, I need to understand why and how to replace that